# Emulator for Redmi devices

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been trying to test my apk on all the commonly used Android devices, and I am doing so with the help of Emulator skins, but I could only get the Emulator skins for Samsung devices. They provide the Emulator skins on their Official Website.

http://developer.samsung.com/emulator/emulatorOverview.do

And now i want to test my apk on Xiaomi, Lenovo and Moto devices, but couldn't find a way to do so. Could anyone please tell me if there is any possibility to get the Emulator skins of these devices or any other alternative.

Comment: Are you aware that skins only change the appearance of the GUI and nothing else?

Comment: No, i was not. Thanks for the information. Is there any option to simulate the apk on Emulators as it is not possible to get it done on physical devices?

Comment: None that I would know of. It would require separate emulators capable of running proprietary firmware for different devices. If you want test device- or firmware-dependent features your best shot is to get real devices.